# jquery mobile disable ui styles formatting

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to ba able to disable all ui classes and html formatting on every page and still be able to use transitions, load pages via ajax, etc...

I looked through the Jquery Mobile documentation and $.mobile js object but could not seem to find anything.

If anyone knows would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Download builder: In the works**
>
> Now that we’ve decoupled most of the UI widgets, we’ve set the stage
>   for there to be a download builder. This will let you build a custom
>   version of jQuery Mobile to only include the parts you need. For
>   example, you could just use the core files to add Ajax-based
>   navigation with pushState and leverage some of the touch events and
>   other utilities with a very lightweight build (roughly 11k). Or, you
>   could add in specific UI widgets like form elements, listviews, etc.
>   to create an optimized build. We’re aiming to have a download builder
>   tool as part of 1.0.

Source:

- http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/09/08/jquery-mobile-beta-3-released/

Comment: I think when 1.0 is officially released, you can also follow development on the blog as well: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/